# AirFlow DAG Duration

Tags: airflow, airflow-2.x

I have an AirFlow job running. It literally takes minimum of 5mins(not consistant) to get my logs started after the job starts.

This increases the overall duration of my job.

I have no idea or any logs on what the job is doing for the initial 5 mins. Is there a way to know this?

Is there a way to reduce the overall job duration in AirFlow.

Thanks,

Comment: which airflow version are u using ? what kind of executor ?

Comment: I need more details, local/sequential executor ? how do install airflow ? if you can share your DAG it be very helpful